# How to simply catch an empty list in Python from JSON API?

Tags: python, json, list, python-requests

I need to return a bunch of SKUs from a JSON API response but sometimes it's "empty":

```
{'products': [], 'request_speed': 0.0015690326690674}
```

This code works when there are products but raises an `IndexError` when there are no products:

```
data = json.loads(r.text)
print(data)
if not data['products'][0]:
    print("something")
    for key in data['products']:
        print(key['info']['sku'])
else:
    print("nothing")
```

And this always has "something" because there is always a "products" `[]` in the response:

```
data = json.loads(r.text)
print(data)
if not data['products']:
    print("something")
    for key in data['products']:
        print(key['info']['sku'])
else:
    print("nothing")
```

I know I could add a try/except to the first example but it seems a round the houses way of achieving something.

Is there a more shorthand way of achieving this?  I did think:

```
if 'info' in data['products']:
```

Was the pythonic way but this always returns "nothing".

Comment: Your check is wrong. `if not data['products']:` should be `if data['products']:`.
You could also check: `if any(data['products']):`

Comment: Yes, the second attempt should work if you fix the condition.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do this check at all.

You can simply iterate over the empty list. It won't do anything if there is nothing.:

```
data = json.loads(r.text)
for key in data['products']:
    print(key['info']['sku'])
```

**EDIT**

If you want to stop your iteration:

```
if not data['products']:
    break
for key in data['products']:
    print(key['info']['sku'])
```

Comment: Except this code is in a while loop to iterate through page 1, 2, etc so I need to check whether this is the last record as the API returns no products.

Comment: The if not data[‘products’]: will always be true as there is always products, just it’s an empty list when there aren’t any.

Comment: Try to execute this on your interpreter:
`if not []: print('this list is empty')`

Answer (score 0):

check its len, like this:

```
data = json.loads(r.text)

print(data)

if len(data['products']) > 0:
    print("something")
    for key in data['products']:
        print(key['info']['sku'])

else:
    print("nothing")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'info' in r.text:
```

Also works.  Which option is best practice and I will mark as correct?